# onyx.DatePicker breaks in enyo.Repeater

Tags: javascript, enyo

I am not able to get a `onyx.DatePicker` working inside a `enyo.Repeater`. I set up this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dGNq/9/), which shows my problem. When the `//` in line 6 is removed, it breaks and shows

> Failed to load date time format hash

in my console in Opera Dragonfly.

What is that about, and what to do, to get the `onyx.DatePicker` working?

Comment: I'm investigating this now.  Could have something to do with the way DatePicker creates its child components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations!  You discovered a bug in Enyo.  It turns out the `onSetupItem` handler in DatePicker.js isn't returning a truthy value so the event bubbles up to your `Repeater`.  I have filed a bug (ENYO-2059) and will push a fix up afterwards.

If you want to fix it for yourself go into DatePicker.js and add 'return true;' to the end of `setupYear()`.

As to your 'cannot load date time hash' issue, I suspect it's because you haven't included the g11n library.  I'm not sure I've seen that message before but it would be a non-fatal error and Enyo will default to English.

Comment: thanks for your investigations. And you are right. I did not include the `g11n`library. I will accept your answer.